# Downloading a file from a link

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I have a web page using C# where I want users to be able to click a link (or a linkbutton or a button, I'm not fussy) and have the "Save As" dialog window appear so they can download the file. The file itself is located on another server so I have to use the absolute path (i:\division\department\publicfiles\filename.pot). Does anyone know how to do that?

I looked up the question here and some people suggested webClient.DownloadFile. Except I can't use that because it requires that you already know where the user wants the file to be downloaded to on their computer. Basically what I'm looking for is what happens when you right click on a link and select "save as", but done when you left click on a link.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The file itself is located on another server" to me sounds like it might not be published to the web and thus doesn't have a URL. Therefore a simple anchor tag will not work in this case. I think you're looking for [`Response.TransmitFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy%28vs.80%29.aspx).

When they click on the link, you need to send the file and explicitly set the content type and content-disposition header. Setting the content-disposition header to `attachment` will pop up the save as dialog. Like (untested):

```
Response.ContentType = "application/x-pot";    
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=filename.pot");    
Response.TransmitFile(@"i:\division\department\publicfiles\filename.pot");    
Response.End();
```

Comment: Thank you. That was EXACTLY what I was looking for and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this,

```
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com/folders/yourfile.pdf"  target="_blank" > click to download file </a>
```

Comment: putting **target="_blank"** will be nice !! :)

Comment: That would open the file in another window. Not download it to the client's computer.

Comment: I followed This statement in question "when you right click on a link and select "save as"

Comment: But not the rest of the statement "but done when you left click on a link." What you said only works when people right-click.

Comment: "but done when you left click on a link" this statement does not clearly stats for open save as dialog. It would be be clear if said left and right mouse button should open save as dialog, is n't it?

Answer (score 0):

With HTML5 you could just use the new property `download` in the anchor tag.

The code will look something like

```
<a download href="path/to/the/download/file"> Clicking on this link will force download the file</a>
```

It works on firefox and chrome latest version. Should I mention that I didn't check it in IE? :P

Comment: hi! I am getting Failed - Network error upon clicking the link!